# Highcharts - Why is there extra spacing before the first column and after the last column?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a Highcharts datetime column chart, with several series that which are added and updated dynamically. It appears that the library is producing the chart with a large chunk of space before the first column and after the last column. It's as if the columns are grouped into the center of the chart, while they should be arranged evenly across the space. I have tried adjusting the minPadding and maxPadding of the axis options with no success:

```
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        minPadding: 0,
        maxPadding: 0,
        labels:{
            formatter:function () {
                return Highcharts.dateFormat('%b %e', this.value);
            }
        }
    },
```

Here is an example adapted from the Highcharts demo page which is behaving correctly:

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/ricksuggs/8Gt2y/

While this example which is written by myself, is showing the extra padding:

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/ricksuggs/PRKAJ/36/

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can modify `pointWidth` and `groupPadding/pointPadding` parameter

http://jsfiddle.net/PRKAJ/37/

EDIT: You should define `pointRange`

http://jsfiddle.net/PRKAJ/41/

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.pointRange

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however, that does not address the specific issue that I am experiencing. My columns are grouped towards the center of the chart, too much spacing on the left of the first column, and right of the last column. Please see the images on the original question that I have added to better explain.

Answer (score 0):

From what I'm seeing, example http://jsfiddle.net/ricksuggs/PRKAJ/36/ is showing to me *without* extra padding; unlike on the screenshot by @ricksuggs above, where there is extra padding.

[image: http://jsfiddle.net/ricksuggs/PRKAJ/36/]

I believe the *"problem"* lies within `multiple series with single data points` vs. `a single series with multiple data points`.

With multiple series (=sets) with single data point in each set, columns are grouped together, expecting another grouped data points from another set, thus creating the padding. However, with a single set containing multiple data points, those are distributed evenly creating no additional padding.

**To answer your question, I believe that's why there is extra spacing.** However, I could not find a way how to get rid of it as grouping multiple series into single set with multiple data points has other limitations (hiding series in legend, coloring, ...).