# Highcharts - Starting the chart from the extreme left

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I've 2 questions:-

1) How do I start [column chart](http://jsfiddle.net/W69qX/) from the extreme left?

2) In [bubble chart](http://jsfiddle.net/7Kh8J/), I want that each bubble should've a different name. I tried this:-

```
series: [{  
                    name: 'Coupan1',
                    color: 'rgba(223, 83, 83, .5)',
                    data: [161.2, 51.6],
                },{  
                    name: 'Coupan2',
                    color: 'rgba(223, 83, 83, .5)',
                    data: [161.2, 51.6],
                },{  
                    name: 'Coupan3',
                    color: 'rgba(223, 83, 83, .5)',
                    data: [161.2, 51.6],
                },{  
                    name: 'Coupan4',
                    color: 'rgba(223, 83, 83, .5)',
                    data: [161.2, 51.6],
                },
            ],
```

But instead of bubbles, some random triangles appear with some random values. Here is the incorrect[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Kh8J/1/).
Where I'm going wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by extreme left?  You don't want a yaxis or you want it to start directly next to the axis instead of centered?

Comment: Referring to first point, I advice to familiar with that topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17179393/highcharts-why-is-there-extra-spacing-before-the-first-column-and-after-the-la

Answer (score 0):

For your second question, you have two issues:

1.) Your data is in an incorrect format:

```
data: [[161.2, 51.6]] // array of array, not single array
```

2.) All your series have the same `x,y` values so it drawing them all on top of each other.  The "some random triangles" are just the different markers overlaying each other.  If you want a circle marker for each series, you need to add that as an option.

```
{  
    name: 'Coupan1',
    color: 'rgba(223, 83, 83, .5)',
    data: [[161.2, 51.6]],
    marker: {symbol: 'circle'}
}
```

Updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7Kh8J/3/).

For the first question, if you don't want the space between the yAxis and the bars, set the group padding to 0.

```
       plotOptions: {
            column: {
                borderWidth: 0
            },                
            series: {
                groupPadding: 0
            }
        },
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W69qX/1/).

Comment: Thanks for the solution. In Bubbles chart, why is the order of the coupans is not maintained? As in the first bubble is couple4, second is coupan3, third is coupan1 and last is coupan2. Why's that? Is it because of the dictionary I'm passing in?

Comment: The data is an x,y coordinate.  It is placing the point at the x position specified.  Also, note, this is a scatter chart, a real bubble chart also has a radius component to the size of the marker.  Highcharts can draw those as well:  http://jsfiddle.net/7Kh8J/4/

Answer (score 0):

Answer to 2nd question:

There are different markers available for each array object. If you want same marker for each of your array object you need to add the marker tag as shown in the below code:

```
series: [{
    name: 'Coupan',
    color: 'rgba(223, 83, 83, .5)',
    data: [[161.2, 51.6]],
    marker: {symbol: 'circle'}
 },{
    name: 'Coupan 2',
    color: 'rgba(223, 83, 83, .5)',
    data: [[167.5, 59.0]],
    marker: {symbol: 'circle'}
 }]
```

This will solve your issue.